# Collection<String>

Tags: java, generics

Whats the main difference between a Collection of String (Collection)and a simple, plain collection?

Comment: See also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2770321/what-is-a-raw-type-and-why-shouldnt-we-use-it

Answer (score 7, accepted):

A plain `Collection` will accept any kind of `Object`, while a `Collection<String>` will only accept `String`s.

If instead of `String` you had a `Collection` of something that could be extended, say `Collection<List>`, then the collection would accept anything that is a subtype of `List`.  [Sun's Java Tutorial on Generics](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/tutorial/java/generics/) is a good place to go to learn more.

Comment: @Koen: Thanks.  I forgot that the WMD parser cancels those out unless you put it in code spans.

Comment: Thanks for the notification. I thought that same first when I saw my post and then realised the obvious.

Answer (score 3):

Once compiled, nothing... But it can help you not to try to put any other object than a String while coding, and you don't have to cast back the objects that you retrieve from the collection.

Answer (score 1):

collection is generics, and it is used to define which type of data it is going to handle, precautions for runtime error, its better it tells you at compile time. so simple collection can accept any thing but collection of string will only accept string.

Answer (score 0):

Generics.
using a Collection as an argument or as  a return type ensures that the caller/accessor to anticipate the objects to be present in the collection.
this helps to avoid unnecessary casting to String.

Type erasure ensures that the generic definition is removed at runtime.A feature which helps in backward compalitibility.